# Update with composer

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

We've took over a magento store. Whenever I try to update, I'm getting the following errors:

```
  Problem 1
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.2.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.4 requires magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.4 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-metapackage[1.1.4].
    - magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.4 requires magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-installer[1.1.0].
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.3.4 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.4].
```

I've tried removing the composer.lock file however it didn't change anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2.3 still requires a composer version below two (so 1.x.x)
Try downgrading your composer with the following command and try again

`composer self-update --1`
(maybe you have to use `sudo composer self-update --1` if you are on UX system, eg Linux or Mac)

Afterwards if you need to go back to version 2 of composer, use the same command just replace the version
`composer self-update --2`

Comment: Thank you. I've assumed my hosting company was using both versions since using composer 2 requires to use 'composer2' in cli.

Comment: Maybe it was like this until recently. But glad it's now working for you